# Select in select to compute a new field

Tags: sql, count, subquery, firebird

Suppose a Firebird (v.2.5) Table name `TREE` has two columns `NODE_ID` and `PARENT_NODE`. I would like to make a query to get records with `NODE_ID = 1` and calculate a new field `CHILD_COUNT`.

In that query, `CHILD_COUNT` must contain the number of records (in the same table) where `PARENT_NODE = NODE_ID`.

My start query is:

```
SELECT NODE_ID, PARENT_NODE, (select count(*) from TREE where PARENT_NODE = NODE_ID) as CHILD_COUNT
FROM TREE
WHERE PARENT_NODE = 1;
```

With that query, `CHILD_COUNT` is always 0. How can I do this query to get `CHILD_COUNT` process for all `TREE` table rows?

Comment: *...make query to get records with NODE_ID = 1* but your WHERE clause is: `WHERE PARENT_NODE = 1`

Comment: Can you tell what’s the input and what would be the output?

Comment: Please provide the necessary DDL, sample table population (preferably as inserts), and the expected output for that sample population. And as forpas says, it looks like your query condition is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the condition in the subquery:

```
where parent_node = node_id
```

This searches for rows where both values are equal, which is not what you want: you want rows whose parent is equal to the node in the *outer query*. For this, you need to *correlate* the subquery with the outer query. So, prefix the columns with the alias of the table they belong to:

```
select node_id, parent_node, 
    (select count(*) from tree t1 where t1.parent_node = t.node_id) as child_count
from tree t                           -- ^ --         -- ^ --
where parent_node = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. For this requirement, the correct code is pasted below

   > Suppose a Firebird (v.2.5) Table name TREE have two columns NODE_ID
   > and PARENT_NODE, I would like to make query to get records with
   > NODE_ID = 1

   ```
   SELECT NODE_ID, PARENT_NODE
   FROM TREE
   WHERE NODE_ID = 1
   ```
2. For the complete request, you will need to do a self join to the table itself.

   ```
   SELECT 
     T1.Node_ID, 
     T1.Parent_mode,
     T22.CHILD_COUNT

   FROM TREE T1, 
   (
       SELECT T2.Node_ID, COUNT(*) as CHILD_COUNT
       FROM TREE t2
       WHERE NODE_ID = 1
       Group by T2.Node_ID
   ) as T22
   WHERE  T1.PARENT_NODE = T22.NODE_ID
   ```